# R: Distance between point and line in meters in GIS data

Tags: r, geometry, gis, distance

I have the longtitudes and latitudes of a bunch of points and lines (and potentially polygons) that I need to measure the distances between in R.

Most people suggest that I use the **gDistance** function from the **rgeos** library. This function requires a bunch of conversions of the longtitudes and latitudes before it outputs the results in **meters**. I have run through numerous tutorials, but still something goes wrong. I hope you can help me catch the error.

First we create some points and lines

```
# Points
points <- data.frame(long = c(12.5633074637037,12.54638671875,12.6039819633632,12.54638671875,12.5668119504436,12.54638671875,12.5482921600342,12.5428380966187,12.5983709560864,12.5914064335047),
                     lat = c(55.6730208606487,55.6685371398926,55.6592116097919,55.6685371398926,55.6855954585358,55.6685371398926,55.7007255554199,55.6902847290039,55.663807868529,55.684380959963))

# Lines
lines <- data.frame(id = c("a", "b"))
lines$matrices <- list(matrix(c(12.5737695648244,12.5736645937496,12.5729168988113,12.5722100725459,12.5720446280546,55.6793201903946,55.6792991790095,55.6791495067552,55.6790112547884,55.6789788981105), ncol = 2),
                       matrix(c(12.5763890840661,12.57598090855,12.5759575726618,12.5757666379295,12.5757392134412,55.6799504343614,55.6797510847791,55.6797426062619,55.6796732345451,55.6796625397541), ncol = 2))
```

Second the data is converted into spatial coordinates using the **sp** library. For the conversion I used a projection in Denmark, as this is where my data is located. I aditionally set the units to meters. The proj.4 was fetched from https://epsg.io/23032.

```
# Libraries
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

# Converting to spatial coordinates
points$sp <- lapply(1:10, function(i) SpatialPoints(points[i,c("long", "lat")], proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")))
lines$sp <- lapply(lines$matrices, function(x) SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(x), ID="a")), proj4string=CRS("+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")))
```

To make a sanity check I plotted the data using **leaflet**. Don't mind the ugly code, I know it could be done smarter with a spatial dataframe. The small blue lines in the middle are the ones I need to measure the distance to.

```
# Library
library(leaflet)

# Plotting to visualize
leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(data = points$sp[[1]], label = "1", labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T)) %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(data = points$sp[[2]], label = "2", labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T)) %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(data = points$sp[[3]], label = "3", labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T)) %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(data = points$sp[[4]], label = "4", labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T)) %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(data = points$sp[[5]], label = "5", labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T)) %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(data = points$sp[[6]], label = "6", labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T)) %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(data = points$sp[[7]], label = "7", labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T)) %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(data = points$sp[[8]], label = "8", labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T)) %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(data = points$sp[[9]], label = "9", labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T)) %>%
  addLabelOnlyMarkers(data = points$sp[[10]], label = "10", labelOptions = labelOptions(noHide = T)) %>%
  addPolylines(data = lines$sp[[1]]) %>%
  addPolylines(data = lines$sp[[2]])
```

[image]

As the data looks great I continued to calculating the distance between the points and the lines

```
# Calculating distances to the lines
## Distance to line 1
lapply(1:10, function(i) gDistance(points$sp[[i]], lines$sp[[1]]))

[[1]]
[1] 0.01057527

[[2]]
[1] 0.02770124

[[3]]
[1] 0.03629248

[[4]]
[1] 0.02770124

[[5]]
[1] 0.008435626

[[6]]
[1] 0.02770124

[[7]]
[1] 0.03220399

[[8]]
[1] 0.03131842

[[9]]
[1] 0.02908369

[[10]]
[1] 0.01834859
```

Obviously the output is not in meters, but possibly in degrees. Can someone point me to where it all goes wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that if I use a different projection, and then afterworth use **spTransform**, I get the desired results. I am not sure, I understand this process, but it does what I was after.

```
# Converting to spatial coordinates
points$sp <- lapply(1:10, function(i) SpatialPoints(points[i,c("long", "lat")], proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")))
points$sp <- lapply(1:10, function(i) spTransform(points$sp[[i]], CRS("+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")))

lines$sp <- lapply(lines$matrices, function(x) SpatialLines(list(Lines(Line(x), ID="a")), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")))
lines$sp <- lapply(1:2, function(i) spTransform(lines$sp[[i]], CRS("+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")))
```

The distances in meters

```
lapply(1:10, function(i) gDistance(points$sp[[i]], lines$sp[[1]]))
[[1]]
[1] 861.6909

[[2]]
[1] 1989.797

[[3]]
[1] 2937.754

[[4]]
[1] 1989.797

[[5]]
[1] 807.0334

[[6]]
[1] 1989.797

[[7]]
[1] 2845.563

[[8]]
[1] 2227.443

[[9]]
[1] 2319.78

[[10]]
[1] 1244.597
```